# New NSDictionary entry not in right order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of `NSString` values called `sortedRefs` and each of them is also a key to a `NSDictionary` called `quotes`.

What I 'm trying to do is pass that key into a new `NSDictionary` with its related value if a condition is met.

```
for (NSString *key in sortedRefs) {
    NSLog(@"%@", key);
    if ([[self.quotesManager.quotes[key] valueForKey:@"active"] boolValue]) {
        [self.activeQuotes setObject:self.quotesManager.quotes[key] forKey:key];
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.activeQuotes allKeys]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `activeQuotes` dictionary is not populated in the order I insert values in. To be more specific my output after the first three loops is

```
2016-05-26 23:10:59.939 Project[2553:94502] DE2109D0C637CBD755E91ED18F85C17E
2016-05-26 23:10:59.940 Project[2553:94502] (
    DE2109D0C637CBD755E91ED18F85C17E
)
2016-05-26 23:10:59.940 Project[2553:94502] 309FFEB2DEC0F938D3E5FFD39112F9F6
2016-05-26 23:10:59.940 Project[2553:94502] (
    DE2109D0C637CBD755E91ED18F85C17E,
    309FFEB2DEC0F938D3E5FFD39112F9F6
)
2016-05-26 23:10:59.940 Project[2553:94502] 925DEC6CFB3FDF87530677FE93E97A46
2016-05-26 23:10:59.940 Project[2553:94502] (
    925DEC6CFB3FDF87530677FE93E97A46,
    DE2109D0C637CBD755E91ED18F85C17E,
    309FFEB2DEC0F938D3E5FFD39112F9F6
)
```

As you can see when I insert `925DEC6CFB3FDF87530677FE93E97A46` instead of going after the `309FFEB2DEC0F938D3E5FFD39112F9F6` key it goes on top. As the loops go on this happens more frequently and I end up with a completely different order than the one I had in the `sortedRefs` array.

Is there a way to keep the order while inserting new entries in my dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary by definition isn't sorted or ordered. If you need them in an order then a dictionary is the wrong choice of data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are not stored in any guaranteed order.  They are designed to be referenced by key.  If you want to access them in a particular order, you need to keep an ordered collection of the keys (e.g. array) and use that to choose them.